# Stop macOS from switching spaces when opening links/files

Tags: spaces, mission-control

My question is a variation of [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112598/microsoft-word-forcing-spaces-switching#new-answer?newreg=5ab0e6331be048f9b06dcecc77a34105). Since the answer to that one doesn't solve mine, I decide to post a new question.

In my "Mission Control" parameters, "When switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application" is unchecked.
When I click on an application in the Dock, the application in question is brought into focus without switching to a window where that application is active, which is expected.

However, when I open a link in `Mail.app` or open a file in `Finder.app`, instead of opening a new window, this would switch to a space where that application has a window and open it in that space, which is annoying. Instead, I want the file to simply be open with its associated program in the current space.
How can I work around this annoying behaviour?

Thank you :)

**Update**:
I just found [this solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4995042?answerId=21918357022#21918357022) from Apple's forum. It did stop switching spaces, but still opens the links in another space. It's even less usable since I don't might click a couple of times without realizing that the tabs were being opened somewhere else.

Comment: @Thinkr That's the post I was referring to when I wrote the update. It still opens the links, I just don't see them because it isn't switching.

Comment: Sorry, I went on this question before you updated and I left it in its own tab and continued to browse on another tab. When I realised I had this tab still opened, I went back on it (no reload) and decided to search a bit about it (what I did), I then found this link and posted it here. :)

Comment: @Thinkr It's okay. I appreciate your help, it's just that I was frustrated with macOS.
Thank you for trying to help :)